# How to get the deepest call stack entry in ERRORLOG.txt?

Tags: c++, exception, callstack

In my company, we are using a crash detection mechanism, similar to the one, explained in [this URL](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5257/XCrashReport-Exception-Handling-and-Crash-Reportin). In case of a crash, this gives following information in `ERRORLOG.TXT` file:

```
Exception handler called in <Object>::<Method>.
```

While verifying the actual crash dump, the call stack looks like this:

```
<Object>::<Method> calls
  <Object>::<SubMethod> calls
    <OtherObject>::<OtherMethod>
      ...
      <AgainOtherObject>::<DeepestSubMethod>
```

In lots of cases, those are caused by `out-of-memory` errors, which are easily recognisable by the `DeepestSubMethod`, being `memcpy`, `ApplicationCopy`, ...

In order to recognise those, I'd like to put the following information in `ERRORLOG.TXT` (just the highest and lowest callstack entry):

```
Exception handler called in <Object>::<Method>, ..., <AgainOtherObject>::<DeepestSubMethod>
```

I could then launch a grep on the `ERRORLOG.TXT` files, like:

```
grep -v -i -E "memcpy|ApplicationCopy|..."
```

This would allow me to filter only the crashes, not caused by out-of-memory exceptions (the actual software bugs I'm looking for).

Unfortunately, the information in `ERRORLOG.TXT` seems to come from `GetExceptionInformation()`, a function, defined in

```
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\excpt.h`.
```

Is there another way to get information from an exception, covering not only the highest part, but also the lowest part of its callstack?